# Entity Framework Core Add and also update related object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and I am trying to understand how update of related entity can be performed. I am using the below code to update the related entity.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cp = new Payment
        {
                CustomerId = vm.SelectedCustomerID,
                PaymentAmount = Convert.ToInt32(vm.PaymentAmount),
                PaymentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(vm.PaymentDate),
                PaymentMethod = await _context.PaymentMethod.SingleAsync(pm => pm.PaymentMethodName == vm.PaymentMethod),
                TransactionType = await _context.TransactionType.SingleAsync(tt => tt.TransactionTypeName == "PaymentReceived")
        };

        Customer c = await _context.Customer.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CustomerId == vm.SelectedCustomerID);

        int updatedOutstandingAmount = c.CurrentAmountOutstanding - cp.PaymentAmount;
        c.CurrentAmountOutstanding = updatedOutstandingAmount;

        _context.Update(c);
        _context.Add(cp);

    }
}
```

There is a related Customer object in Payment class but since I am inserting the new record of payment, and also at the same time, i need to update the outstandingamount which is customer attribute, I wonder how I can attach the customer entity to this Payment and run the insert and update at one transaction. or the way I have done below is correct way ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use an explicit transaction as all `SaveChanges` calls to EF are performed within a transaction anyway. So the only other thing your missing is actually calling `SaveChanges`

Comment: @ChadT , yeah I understood that... question I was asking is calling  _context.Update and _context.Add is right way for the case above.